# How do I get Info from an Array into a message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

I'm storing some info in an array like this:

```
array = [{ name:'name1', id:'id1' }, { name:'name2', id:'id2' }, { name:'name3', id:'id3'}];
```

I want to send a message from the bot back to the user with all the names in the array. How do I go about doing this?

Normally, I would use a for loop to cycle through for comparisons and such but I don't want to send multiple messages. Just want one to respond back so I don't think I'm supposed to use a for loop.

For clarification, this is what I would like the response from the Discord bot to look like:

"name1's ID is id1, name2's ID is id2, name3's ID is id3"

Also the array can change. That's something I realized I should probably let everyone know. So the array starts empty and then has random names pushed to it. So when someone uses the right command I want it to reply with every name in the array regardless of the length of the array.

Comment: (please note that arrays are made using `[]` not `()`)

Comment: Yes you should use `[]` around your object list. To iterate element of the array one by one you have multiple ways. Here is my two favorites: 
`array.forEach(element => {//your code});` or `for (var element of array){//your code}`

Comment: Please provide a format you wish to send the names back? As single names in a new array, in an object?

Comment: The () were a mistake when making this question. They are in []

Comment: @Brettski I want them sent as a message back to the user on discord. Sorry I forgot to include the information in my original post

Comment: You have a couple approaches as answers here to do that. If you would provide what the result needs to look like to send back to Discord then I am sure people would be happy to update their answer for that specific use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this, and yes they involve some type of loop. A for loop is usually the fastest, but if there is only a few items, this will not matter. There is also `Array.forEach()` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and `Array.reduce()` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### using a forEach:

```js
const array = [{name: "name1", id: "id1"}, {name: "name2", id: "id2"}, {name: "name3", id: "id3"}]
const itemCount = array.length;
const output = ''

array.forEach(item, idx => {
  output += `${item.name}'s ID is ${item.id}${idx < itemCount ? ', ' : ''}`
}

return output
```

### using reduce

```js
const array = [{name: "name1", id: "id1"}, {name: "name2", id: "id2"}, {name: "name3", id: "id3"}]
const itemCount = array.length;

return array.reduce((acc, item, idx) => {
  acc += `${item.name}'s ID is ${item.id}${idx < itemCount ? ', ' : ''}`
  return acc;
}, '');
```

### for loop

```js
const array = [{name: "name1", id: "id1"}, {name: "name2", id: "id2"}, {name: "name3", id: "id3"}]
const output = ''

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
  const item = array[i];
  output += `${item.name}'s ID is ${item.id}${idx < itemCount ? ', ' : ''}`
}

return output;
```

There is probably a bug or two up there, but I hope you get the general idea. The `${idx < itemCount ? ', ' : ''}` is just a messy way to not add a comma on the last item.

Comment: I never really thought to use a for loop to generate the whole message. This makes a lot more sense to use a for loop in this way though. Thank you

Comment: Don't discount the the other array iterators, they are quite powerful in their own ways. It took me some time to get accustom to them, but them so very useful now.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through with reduce, that way you can return whatever you want from the array (string for example).

```
const message = array.reduce((accumulated, currentObj) => {
    return acc + currentObj.name + ', ';
}, '');
```

// will return name, name, name

Comment: This looks useful but what if I wanted to use each one separately? Like for instance if I wanted the bottom to send back “{name}’s ID is {id}\n{other name}’s ID is {other id}”

Comment: @Chaimm's example uses a `reduce` function off of an array details here: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). In each iteration (element in the array) you can format the string the way you want prior to adding it to the accumulator (`acc`). so something like return accumulated += \`${currentObj.name}'s ID is ${currentObj.id}\`